# keystonejs form processing documentation location

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

Does anyone have a source/documentation on the keystone js model method "getUpdateHandler" and the handler method "process" found here https://gist.github.com/wuhaixing/e90b8497f925ff9c7bfc under "form post"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this part of the codebase is currently not really documented at all. There's a small discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/keystonejs/XDpFz28D4W8), which you may find helpful, but I'll summarise the key points below:

The idea behind the update handler is to allow you to easily update your fields from the front end of your site. You tell it which fields you'd like to update, and give it the relevant data. It then checks your model which allows it to handle any validation errors etc itself and provided all is fine it'll do the necessary operations to update your field.

You can see the process function itself [here](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/master/lib/updateHandler.js#L40), and there are a few comments which may be helpful, but this is by no means documentation. Further, there is a good example on the SydJS site (links to the [backend code (route)](https://github.com/JedWatson/sydjs-site/blob/master/routes/views/me.js#L32) and the [frontend code (template)](https://github.com/JedWatson/sydjs-site/blob/master/templates/views/site/me.jade#L19)). Hopefully, that should be enough to get you started.